# dynamically populate tables based on database table

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table like this

[image]

I have a ux control which looks like this

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Up1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc:LocalTable ID="Table1" runat="server" CssClass="SomeClass" AllowPaging="False"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" Caption="Table 1" PagerPosition="TopAndBottom" SelectedRowStyle="selectedStyle"
                Width="100%" GenerateOnClick="False">

                <Columns>
                        <uc:TableTemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderResource="" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <input type="checkbox" name="chk<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>"  id="chkCatelog" <%# Eval("IsChecked").ToString()=="1"?"checked=\"checked\"":"" %> />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </uc:VetsXLTemplateField>
                        <uc:TableBoundField DataField="SomeID" HeaderText="GuidID"></uc:TableBoundField>
                        <uc:TableBoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Country"></uc:TableBoundField>
                        <uc:TableBoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Manufacturar"></uc:TableBoundField>                           
                    </Columns>
            </uc:TableTable>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Based on the database table I would like to dynamically populate 7 tables and fill these tables with data from another table also dynamically. I ahve done that statically but I am not really sure how to do it dznamically.

Anz help or advice would be grate

Answer (score 0):

Make **AutoGenerateColumns="true"** & remove

```
<uc:TableTemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderResource="" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>"  id="chkCatelog" <%# Eval("IsChecked").ToString()=="1"?"checked=\"checked\"":"" %> />
    </ItemTemplate>
</uc:VetsXLTemplateField>
<uc:TableBoundField DataField="SomeID" HeaderText="GuidID"></uc:TableBoundField>
<uc:TableBoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Country"></uc:TableBoundField>
<uc:TableBoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Manufacturar"></uc:TableBoundField>
```

Comment: Hi Rajan,

I want to do all these things in the code behind file. Starting from the creation of the table and its columns to populating them with data from the database. Everything should be done dynamically,